# amcharts pdf export , export logo image from a url to server to PDF

Tags: javascript, pdf, report, amcharts

I am trying to implement the example provided on the following link http://www.amcharts.com/tutorials/export-charts-advanced/ and its working fine. 
In the sample PDF layout they a have predefined image for logo, this is a base64 PNG image. my problem is that i have taken and saved the logo image  from user to be used in reports.Image is on a specific known location at server which might be accessed through a URL in my java script. but how can i access this image and reference it in my PDF layout so that it can be used as an header or logo image in my PDF reports.
whether there's a method to provide the image URL instead of providing a static base64 image data or do i need to write a function to to get image from server and convert it to a base64 image data and assign it to the logo attribute in the PDF layout. 
please watch the sample layout at following link http://extra.amcharts.com/support/export/report/layouts/layout_1.js

in the above link i am concerned about the last part "**predefined images**" i want to get this image from my server with a URL or with any suggested method.

Kindly help.

Thank you.

Comment: You could use something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150289/how-to-convert-image-into-base64-string-using-javascript
Look at the second answer.

Comment: could you please check the sample PDF layout , i have provide a link to that , in the last portion there is "predefined images attribute" how do i assign the value to the "logo" attribute ?

Comment: my image file is inside the upload folder in root directory with the name "logo.png"

Comment: i have tried implementing the solution at following link <http://jsfiddle.net/handtrix/YvQ5y/> but it returns me a Incomplete or corrupt PNG file